# How to use Source.queue with Alpakka

Tags: java, jms, akka-stream, alpakka

I'm trying to create a producer to a JMS queue that can be used more than once; i.e., I don't want to create a connection to the queue every time I send a message. I want an actor with a connection open, and each time a message comes in, it uses that same flow.

Actor init

```
 Sink<String, CompletionStage<Done>> jmsSink = JmsProducer
        .textSink(
            JmsProducerSettings
                .create(connectionProvider.get())
                .withQueue(queueName)
        );

 someActor = Source
        .queue(Integer.MAX_VALUE, OverflowStrategy.backpressure())
        .runWith(jmsSink, materializer); // it doesn't like jmsSink, it wants a graph
```

Actor onMessage

```
 someActor.tell(foo); // something like this
```